# how do i split ip address value from database into the array format in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, ip

I'm working on the CodeIgniter application where I want to split IP address into the array format. Actually, I'm getting values from the database column but unable to create the array from the dynamic values which are getting from the database?

**Controller Code**

```
Getting Values from the database 

$system = $this->Xin_model->read_enter_allow_ip_address_info(1);
$allowlist =  array($system[0]->enter_allow_ip_address);
$finalipallow = nl2br($allowlist);

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$finalipallow)){
$Return['error'] = 'Login Failed';  
$this->output($Return); 
}
```

**Models Query**

```
public function read_enter_allow_ip_address_info($id) {

    $condition = "setting_id =" . "'" . $id . "'";
    $this->db->select('enter_allow_ip_address');
    $this->db->from('xin_system_setting');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Dynamic Values From The Database Column**

```
'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'
```

**how do I split IP address values from database into the array format like this static array**

```
$finalipallow = array(
        '10.0.0.1',
        '10.0.0.2',
        '10.0.0.3',
        '::1'
);
```

I have a static array which is working with `if condition` but I want to convert dynamic values into the array like the static array?

**Working now here the solution of it**

```
$system = $this->Xin_model->read_enter_allow_ip_address_info(1);
$allowlist =  $system[0]->enter_allow_ip_address;

$finalipallow = str_getcsv($allowlist, ",", "'");

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$finalipallow)){
   $Return['error'] = 'Login Failed';   
   $this->output($Return);  
}
```

Comment: `$finalipallow = explode(',', $system[0]->enter_allow_ip_address);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to process it as a CSV record...

```
$data = "'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'";
$finalipallow = str_getcsv($data, ",", "'");

print_r($finalipallow);
```

which outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10.0.0.1
    [1] => 10.0.0.2
    [2] => 10.0.0.3
    [3] => ::1
)
```

Just change `$data` to the value from the database.  Using the deimter and the optional enclosed parameters allows it to strip off the extra quotes from the data.

Comment: still same result like this `'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'`

Comment: I've changed the code to be clearer, it this what your expecting.

Comment: you have created the static array `$data = "'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'";` I have the static array `$finalipallow = array(
        '10.0.0.1',
        '10.0.0.2',
        '10.0.0.3',
        '::1'
);` which is working fine but convert dynamic values into the array format like this `$finalipallow = array(
        '10.0.0.1',
        '10.0.0.2',
        '10.0.0.3',
        '::1'
);`

Comment: The output of my code gives you the same thing as your after - it's the same start point as the other answer but gives the final array without quotes round the values.

Comment: brother I don't have 15 reputation mark it as answered required 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` which will split the string and return the items in an array

```
$newArray = explode(',',$dbString);
```

`print_r($newArray);` <-- you can view the data

```
$dbString=  "'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'";
$newArray = explode(',',$dbString);
print_r($newArray);
```

output: `Array ( [0] => '10.0.0.1' [1] => '10.0.0.2' [2] => '10.0.0.3' [3] => '::1' )`

You will need to replace `'` with empty string since I can see you are comparing exact IP with array. You can do it like this:

```
$dbString=  "'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'";
$dbString= str_replace("'", "", $dbString);
$newArray = explode(',',$dbString);
print_r($newArray);
```

**or you can change**

```
`if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$newArray)`)
```

to

```
if(!in_array("'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'",$newArray))
```

Comment: still same result like this '10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3','::1'

Comment: dynamic values should be like this `$finalipallow = array(
        '10.0.0.1',
        '10.0.0.2',
        '10.0.0.3',
        '::1'
);`

Comment: i have try your example code but if condition not working `if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$newArray))`